# How to open multiple windows/session in iOS app?

Tags: ios, session, multiple-instances

I am working on an app which is a Server based App, User establish a connection/session with Server and do what he wants. (For Example Lets say this is `SessionScreen`:- one Session is - http://postimg.org/image/xog0l04wl/)

Now App requires one more feature, which is multiple Session. Lets say in Safari Browser we have multiple tab and we can switch from one tab to other. But in My app I can not add any tab because App don't need any tab (Only `SessionScreen`(shown above) should be visible on whole screen/visibleView, no any `TabViewController`).

Can I handle Multiple `SessionScreen` using `Gestures` instead of using tab like Safari?

Further, I will add a button on `SessionScreen` Lets Say `NewSessionButton`, it will again create one more Session just Like `SessionScreen`

But the problem is What kind of Layout should I use to display another `SessionScreen` without using `UITabViewController` OR or any tab like safari.

And User should able to switch from one `SessionScreen` to another `SessionScreen` to work in difference sessions.

Let me try to describe the working of App - when we double press Home Button (to kill the app) we can switch form one app to other app (For visualise, see Pic- http://postimg.org/image/8tfqrrkr7/ we can switch From Facebook to Skype). It is not necessary to implement the exactly same as it working, but App need something like this so that user can switch from one `SessionScreen` to other `SessionScreen` using `Gestures`.

Let me summarise it again- User able to create the Multiple Session,and able to switch from one session to other. I can not use TabViewController OR tab like Safari. I can use any of gestures for this.

Any idea how can I start to implement this? I also saw one link that implements TableViews inside the scrollview, not able to post here due to the lack of reputations, posting that in comments. Not able to get idea from that link.

Comment: This link https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/paneltableview . I am not getting how to use this concept.

Comment: This question will likely be closed too. It's asking for people's opinion. This type of question is off-topic.

Comment: Ok rmaddy: should I delete this question ?

Comment: Thank You rmaddy : Actuly I am asking for approach how can I start this. not for Opinions.